# List all Azure DevOps Projects with Reactjs

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to list all the projects that were returned from my API call with React. I currently only have the C# code that gets all the projects that the user has authorization for and displays it in JSON format. Hardcoded the personalaccesstoken in the code (because I don't know how else to do it tbh). Now, I wish to list all the projects returned with React so that the user can select the desired project they want to work on from a dropdown menu.

I have little experience with React and have never used it with REST API's.

( If someone has the answer to the question above, I would greatly appreciate the help with another problem. I'm also trying to create a new repository in the project that the user has selected, and I want them to be able to specify the name of this repository with an input field. Once the user has specified the desired repository name and chosen the project from the dropdown menu, they should be able to hit "Submit" in order to start a POST Request to the REST API and create the new repository in the project. This will also be done with React. )

Answer (score 0):

You may need check this code repos: [azure-devops-node-api-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/tree/master/samples). We have done provide the sample code in that repo.

[**Get project**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/417f07133a7f6e2b18745afbdca6268fcc7801a8/api/CoreApi.ts#L765):

```
public async getProjects(
        stateFilter?: any,
        top?: number,
        skip?: number,
        continuationToken?: string,
        getDefaultTeamImageUrl?: boolean
        ): Promise<CoreInterfaces.TeamProjectReference[]> {

        return new Promise<CoreInterfaces.TeamProjectReference[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let routeValues: any = {
            };

            let queryValues: any = {
                stateFilter: stateFilter,
                '$top': top,
                '$skip': skip,
                continuationToken: continuationToken,
                getDefaultTeamImageUrl: getDefaultTeamImageUrl,
            };

            try {
                let verData: vsom.ClientVersioningData = await this.vsoClient.getVersioningData(
                    "6.0-preview.4",
                    "core",
                    "603fe2ac-9723-48b9-88ad-09305aa6c6e1",
                    routeValues,
                    queryValues);

                let url: string = verData.requestUrl!;
                let options: restm.IRequestOptions = this.createRequestOptions('application/json', 
                                                                                verData.apiVersion);

                let res: restm.IRestResponse<CoreInterfaces.TeamProjectReference[]>;
                res = await this.rest.get<CoreInterfaces.TeamProjectReference[]>(url, options);

                let ret = this.formatResponse(res.result,
                                              CoreInterfaces.TypeInfo.TeamProjectReference,
                                              true);

                resolve(ret);

            }
            catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

You can continue to check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/417f07133a7f6e2b18745afbdca6268fcc7801a8/api/CoreApi.ts) page, it shows you many samples including **create project**.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I am having problems understanding the code and what it does... care to explain?

Comment: @ZEKE, one things need confirm, are you trouble with the part code I shared above? Or confusing on do not know how to read the complete sample github code of the link?

Comment: I'm actually confused with both tbh, trying to understand the code. I see the links include more operations with Azure DevOps, but I don't quite understand how they work, and how to integrate this with my own code.

Comment: @ZEKE did you ever check this get start guide(https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api#get-started)?

Comment: I will have to try it out on a separate project. I didn't realise it was necessary to download the whole library. I was hoping the solution would be easier to understand through the code. I will check it out anyway and let you know if I have any further problems. Thanks for now!